# Navigating from Navigation Drawer common to all activities to fragments

Tags: android, navigation

I have two activities first one displays user list and the second displays detailed user information.I have two common navigation drawer(using BaseActivityApproach) one for app navigation and other for user filter.The user filter drawer is visible only when the user is selected and then it remains selected throughout the application.
So,after selecting a user two navigation drawers are visible throughout the application.Now,suppose i click on a user in first activity so next activity is popped up.Now if i want to navigate through app level drawer ,should i attach fragment to the current activity(displaying detailed user information) or move back to previous activity and attach fragment there.Also if i am in (main user) list activity and i click on the user filter navigation drawer then should i open second activity and attach fragment there or attach fragment in the current activity.
OR please suggest me some better approach for this 
please help.

Comment: you may try using app level drawer on left side and activity specific on right side of the sreen

Comment: sorry forgot to mention..both drawers are on two different sides..but the filter drawer is hidden until a user is selected and remains selected.

Comment: sorry, i cant understand your issue completely,can you point the exact problem

Comment: if i am currently in main activity and user is selected so filter drawer is visible even in main activity .If i click on the filter drawer menu should i attach fragment to mainactivity itself or open detail activity and add that particular fragment thers.